# Why this code does show prime?

Tags: php

I have a code

```
<?php

$num = 20;
echo "Prime: ";
for( $j = 2; $j <= $num; $j++ ) {
 for( $k = 2; $k < $j; $k++ ) {

   if( $j % $k == 0 ) {
         break;
  }
}
if( $k == $j )
 echo $j . ", ";
}

?>
```

Why with this condition **if( $k == $j )** will we have prime as result? Could you explain how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... Why with this condition `if( $k == $j )` will we have prime as result?

Because there's no other number `$k` in the inner `for` loop that perfectly divide `$j`, otherwise it would come out of the inner `for` loop after this executing this block, `if( $j % $k == 0 ) { break; }`

For example, If `$j` is `10`, the inner `for` i.e. `$k` will loop through `2` to `9`. And if any number between 2 to 9 perfectly divides 10, then it will come out of the loop using `break;` statement. In this case, `2` divides `10` perfectly, hence it breaks out of the loop. And during `if( $k == $j ){...` check it sees that `$k`, which is `2`, is not equal to `$j`, which is `10`, hence `10` is not a prime number.

The same logic will follow if `$j` is `11`. The inner `for` loop tries to divide this number with `2`, `3`, ... upto `10` and sees that no number between this range(`2` to `10`) can divide number `11`. So after after coming out of the loop, `$k` will be `11`. Subsequently, this condition will be checked, `if( $k == $j ){...` and since `$k`, which is `11`, equals to `$j`, which is also equals to `11`, the number `11` is prime.

Answer (score 0):

`$k == $j` shows that from 2 to `$j`, non mumber can match `$j % $k = 0`, otherwise it will break in the inner for loop, so it's prime.

Answer (score 0):

A prim is a number, which cannot be divided by a number which is smaller than the number itself (except 1) without a reminder. So in your code if any number is found, which has no reminder you break the inner loop and go ahead. When no reminder less number was found the `$k == $j` and so it is a prime.

Comment: a prime is a number that can be divided only by 1 and itself.

Answer (score 0):

Because if you keep incrementing k and no number is divisible for the value that j has. So from the definition of a prime number(a prime number is a number that can be divided only by himself and one) you have a prime number. Actually you don't have to keep incrementing k until it's equal to j, the square root it's enough to say so. As it's written in wikipedia -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Trial_division